# Laravel 5.6 Changing e-mail address resets login throttle

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, throttling

There's a weird issue with laravel's login throttling. I set the variables:

```
 public $maxAttempts = 5;
 public $decayMinutes = 3;
```

in the Auth/LoginController.php, and override the `sendLockoutResponse` function like this:

```
protected function sendLockoutResponse(Request $request) {
  $seconds = $this->limiter()->availableIn(
      $this->throttleKey($request)
  );

  $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
  $seconds = $seconds % 60;

  return back()->with('authError', 'Wait ' . $minutes . ' minutes and ' . $seconds . ' seconds.');
}
```

When I try 5 failed login attempts using wrong credentials I can see the `AuthError` message on the page. And if I go on with the same e-mail address I continue to see seconds and minutes decrease. But if I change the e-mail the whole throttle gets reset. I still have 5 failed attempts to go.

My question is: if laravel determines a user's login attempts by IP address and uses cache to poll them, why changing the e-mail resets the login throttle?

PS my .env values are:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Laravel docs share the details of the built in throttling

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#login-throttling

as you can read the IP and email address combination is used to track login attempts

I imagine so that if multiple users are logging in from the same IP they all do not get locked out/throttled

You would need to change this to use ID or similar if you want it to act differently